# Нужно ли ставить запятую перед «даже»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, спп

*Поэтому(,) даже если я отвечу, ты вряд ли поймёшь.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятая ставится:

***Поэтому, даже если я отвечу, ты вряд ли поймёшь.***

> [**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=201844)
>
> *Поэтому* – наречие, *если* – союз, присоединяющий придаточное предложение. Если придаточное предложение можно изъять или переставить, оно выделяется с двух сторон запятыми. Корректно: *Поэтому, если я допущу ошибку, меня выгонят с работы*.

**Примеры из Нацкорпуса русского языка:**

**Поэтому, даже если** бы японцы прослышали о советском решении, опасность того, что они предпримут упреждающую акцию в Приморье, стала минимальной. [Валентин Бережков. Рядом со Сталиным (1971-1998)]

Давление атмосферы составляет около шести сотых от земной, **поэтому, даже если бы** она целиком состояла из кислорода, дышать на Марсе было бы все равно невозможно. [Константин Феоктистов. Новые границы у нас под ногами // «Знание - сила», 1997]

**Поэтому, даже если** вы прочли мой первый *раман*, стоит потратить на это введение несколько минут ― будет полезно освежить в памяти ключевые понятия нашего мира. [Виктор Пелевин. Бэтман Аполло (2013)]

---

Если в предложении присутствует второй компонент подчинительного союза ***если... то***, то запятая перед ***если*** не ставится, так как придаточное переставить невозможно. Например:

**Поэтому даже если** малыш говорит «я сам», **то** нельзя это понимать буквально. [Елена Дружинина. А если ребёнку доверить ребёнка? (24.11.2012) // «Новгородские ведомости», 2012]

P. S. К сожалению, далеко не всегда можно ориентироваться на примеры из Нацкорпуса, и этот случай не исключение – пишут кто во что горазд.

Comment: «Если придаточное предложение можно изъять или переставить…» Если учишься в школе, то лучше ориентироваться на это мнение Грамоты.ру.  Ведь про наречие «поэтому» у Розенталя нет конкретной информации, хотя  в его правилах допускается соединение подчинительного союза с присоединительными словами. Но можно ли наречие "поэтому" считать присоединительным? В какой-то мере да, судя по форманту "это"  в его составе, но учащимся не стоит вникать в такие тонкости.

Comment: А вот писателям стоит, для них правило перестановки с его формализмом не способствует решению их конкретных художественных задач. Вот обычное предложение из Нацкорпуса, где, к сожалению (или к счастью), нет однообразия: «Поэтому если кто-то хотел попрыгать с них в песочные кучи, надо было сначала спросить разрешения у Вовки». [Андрей Геласимов. Жанна (2001)] Будем править текст? А вот простая бытовая фраза: «Поэтому если нужно что-то, спрашивай у меня». Здесь обязательно ставить запятую?

Comment: @Sharon правило перестановки 'с его формализмом' указано именно у Розенталя, пусть и не относится конкретно к 'поэтому'. Так что да, Александр ответил правильно, и никаких хронически выдумываемых вами 'тонкостей' тут нет.

Comment: @Sharon Я знал, что вы обязательно станете защищать художественные задачи. :)) Конечно, мы не будем править текст. Пусть пишут как хотят, потому что чётких правил с этим "поэтому" нет, а есть мнения и рекомендации. Когда ж теоретики, наконец, разберут по полочкам такие структуры? Здесь, как мне кажется, должны править грамматика с семантикой, а не интуиция или отсутствие паузы между словами.

Comment: @Nektoid Правило Розенталя относится к союзам, а "поэтому" не союз, а местоименное наречие. (У вас есть правило для местоименных наречий?) И насчет "тонкостей", которые вам так не нравятся и мешают вашей уверенности, что вы все уже знаете о правописании, так что и думать больше не о чем. Странная у вас философия: если я чего-то не вижу, то этого нет?  Отрицание объективно существующей реальности, и всё такое?

Comment: @ Александр Стрелец А мечты о четких правилах – это ваш, Александр,  идеализм:)) Читайте Розенталя: он говорит нам о четкости и однозначности только в орфографии.  Так что по полочкам  никто и ничего разбирать не будет. Мне же, к примеру, достаточно структурного анализа, а также высказывания грамматиков о вставочном характере обособленных  и выделенных таким образом конструкций.

Comment: Иногда решение задает структура (так, в заданном предложении встречаются наречие, частица и подчинительный союз), но в других случаях обособление должно иметь семантическое обоснование. Нужно ли придаточное обособлять/выделять/подчеркивать  и зачем это делать?

Comment: @Sharon Я далеко не всё знаю о правописании и никогда такого не утверждал. Что касается "поэтому", то это слово может быть наречием, а может быть союзным словом (см. БТС). И уж понятно, что во втором варианте правило Розенталя тут вполне подходит.

Comment: @Nektoid Не надо читать БТС, если вам нужны точные знания о грамматике. Уже все дано пришли к выводу, что это именно наречие, а не союзное слово, даже Грамота.ру Цитата: ПОЭТОМУ – указательное местоименное наречие, а не союз. Союзным словом оно тоже не является. gramota.ru/forum/spravka/63517 Также обсуждение вопроса: rus.stackexchange.com/questions/34851/Поэтому-прежде-чем  Но это 2013 год.  В новых учебниках по грамматике четко сказано, что это  союзный аналог, но не союзное слово.  При наличии в предложении "поэтому" оно считается БСП.

Comment: @Sharon вы, похоже, даже не прочитали обсуждение на форуме Грамоты (который, к тому ж, вообще-то не ответы Грамоты, а обычные пользовательские комментарии), Официально же Грамота называет "поэтому" "союзом (точнее, союзным аналогом)" (см. http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_185). Но все эти словесные украшения никак не влияют на то, что по сути "поэтому" в подобных конструкциях выполняет роль союза и, как следствие, подчиняется правилам Розенталя. Так же, как, к примеру, прилагательное, переходящее в разряд существительных, начинает подчиняться правилам существительных.

Comment: Да ладно, я вижу, что это дискуссия конца не имеет.  Ревнители простоты и однозначности в принципе не различают союзы, союзные слова и их аналоги. И никогда не будут из различать. Они любят только проверки в виде перестановок. Вот и пусть занимаются школьной орфографией, а писателей оставят в покое. И я спорить ни с кем не собираюсь - это так сказано, чтобы границы обозначить:  здесь наша правильность, а там ваша.

Comment: @Sharon правда в данном случае одна-едиинственная. Писатель может хоть справа налево вверх ногами писать, но правильным это не станет. Максимум — "авторским взглядом".

Comment: Что так? Вы не доказали, что правило о перестановке относится в наречию "поэтому", значит, применить его здесь нельзя. И что тогда осталось от вашей правды?  Толкнешь — и упадет!

Comment: @Sharon я всё объяснил про функцию союза и провёл аналогию с субстантивацией. Sapienti sat.

Comment: @Nektoid Вы всё себе объяснили, но не мне. Уходите от прямых вопросов, не слышите как бы.  Ну ладно, надеюсь все умные на вашей стороне (они вообще любят собираться в стаи).

Comment: @Sharon лучше быть достойным стаи, чем отары.

Comment: Ладно, я вас прощаю за ваш юмор...  :))